# How to write a Filter ( using DB ) with Highland.js

Tags: highland.js

I'm trying to design a workflow using Highland.js. I have not be able to figure out how Highland.js can used for it.

I have a stream based workflow as below (pseudo code),

```
read                      //fs.createReadStream(...)
   .pipe(parse)           //JSONStream.parse(...)
   .pipe(filterDuplicate) //mongoClient.db.collection.count({}) > 0
   .pipe(transform)       //fn(item) { return tranform(item); }
   .pipe(write);          //mongoClient.db.collection.insert(doc)
```

The filterDuplicate looks up the database to check if read record exists (using a condition) and returns a boolean result. For the filter to work, it needs an active DB connection, which I want to reuse till the stream is complete. One way is have an open a connection before the read and close on 'finish' event of write; This means I need to pass the connection as a param to filter and write, which would work if both methods use the same database.

In the above workflow, filterDuplicate and write may also use different databases. So I would expect the connection to contained and managed with-in each function, which makes it an self-contained reusable unit.

I'm looking for any inputs on how this can be designed using Highland.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be quite as easy as just using `pipe` a bunch of times. You've got to use the most appropriate API method for the task.

Here's a rough example of what you're probably going to end up close to:

```
read
  .through(JSONStream.parse([true]))
  .through((x) => {
    h((next, push) => { // use a generator for async operations
      h.wrapCallback( mongoCountQuery )( params ) // you don't have to do it this way
        .collect()
        .toCallback((err, result) => {
          if ( result > 0 ) push( err, x ); // if it met the criteria, hold onto it
          return push( null, h.nil ); // tell highland this stream is done
        });
    });
  })
  .merge() // because you've got a stream of streams after that `through`
  .map(transform) // just your standard map through a transform
  .through((x) => {
    h((next, push) => { // another generator for async operations
      h.wrapCallback( mongoUpdateQuery )( params )
        .toCallback((err, results) => {
          push( err, results );
          return push( null, h.nil );
        });
    });
  })
  .merge() // another stream-of-streams situation
  .toCallback( cb ); // call home to say we're done
```

Comment: I was looking specifically for highland mechanisms(if any) for maintaining state. In this case an open db connection, for the mongoCountQuery and mongoUpdateQuery and trigger when its appropriate to close. After some reading I think the state should be maintained outside and explicitly passed as a context to the stream processing functions. That way, the stream processing functions just use the context to do their job,  and Highland focuses on co-ordinating the stream functions.

Comment: Four months later, I'm inclined to downvote my own answer.